# JQuery to make div customized scroll bar always visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table content marked with div with height of 200px. Table content is user input & dynamic . I am using JQuery to modulate scroll bar but if i use  **overflow-y: scroll !important;** normal scroll appears at the beginning..
If the div content crosses 200px height then JQuery scroll bar appears along with normal scroll bar.

**What I Want is :**
I  want to show the JQuery scroll bar always visible irrespective of div height but not with normal scroll bar as shown in below image.

> **Error Snapshot:**

[image]

> **CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
#boxscroll {
    height: 200px;
    width: 230px;   
    overflow-y: scroll !important;    }
</style>
```

> **JQuery:**

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
```

Download JQUERY here... https://jquery-nicescroll.googlecode.com/files/jquery.nicescroll.340.zip

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var nicesx = $("#boxscroll").niceScroll({touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#CCC",cursoropacitymax:0.8,cursorwidth:4,autohidemode:false});
  });
</script>
```

> **HTML :**

```
<div  id="boxscroll">
<TABLE id="ItemTable" width="230" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
....content goes here....
</TABLE>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var nicesx = $("#boxscroll").niceScroll({nativeparentscrolling: false,touchbehavior:false,cursorcolor:"#CCC",cursoropacitymax:0.8,cursorwidth:4,autohidemode:false});
  });
</script>
        <style>
        #boxscroll {
            height: 200px;
            width: 230px;   
            overflow-y: hidden;    }
        </style>
```

This should work.

For displaying the scroll bar at any height:

```
.nicescroll-rails div{
    display: inline !important;
    min-height: 30px;
}
.nicescroll-rails {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: i need modified scroll bar not the normal one. Look at the image i have given please...

Comment: So you need to check the library doc to see whether there is a setting for it, or just dig into the source code to change. https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll they have some doc here

Comment: The library doc is not given with always visible scroll bar... and i am sorry, i could not make the changes. thats why posted here :(

Comment: Sorry I misunderstand your qn! All you need is just overflow-y: hidden; and nativeparentscrolling: false. I tried

Comment: Wait wait, this only hides the native. You want show the JQuery scroll bar always visible irrespective of div height. Let me see whether can achieve that

Comment: now it is not showing JQuery scroll bar too.. I want to display the JQuery bar alone as shown in the image

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36229/discussion-between-logan-and-charles-w)

Comment: JQuery bar appears only if div crosses 200px height

Comment: I managed to get this work, but it's very hacky. See my edited answer.

Comment: you have added, nativeparentscrolling: false
its not working.. could you please share me demo ?

Comment: you have added, nativeparentscrolling: false & overflow-y: hidden;
its not working.. could you please share me demo ?

Comment: @Harry , Did you try fadeout concept ?